# using context menu in silverlight 3

Tags: silverlight, xaml, silverlight-3.0

I am new in silverlight. I want to use context menu in  treeview item in my silverlight 3 application .
I have searched in the net regarding this I have found my custom application for this but I am not getting them .How to use context menu, how to add rightclick event for using context menu  .

Thanks in addvance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must do this immediately then this [blog](http://blogs.silverlight.net/blogs/msnow/archive/2008/07/01/tip-of-the-day-14-how-to-right-click-on-a-silverlight-application.aspx) article describes how to use the plugin in `windowless` mode an then borrow the host broweser oncontextmenu event to detect the right mouse button.   However I would hold off if you can and use Silverlight 4 which supports context menus directly.  Its best to avoid windowless mode if you can.

Comment: I am usins silverlight3.I am still not able to set windowless mode in default.aspx to get right click event.

Comment: @ashishtri: What prevents you from enabling windowless mode?  In Silverlight 3 without Windowless mode you have no hope using a context menu.  Is dropping the requirement for a context menu viable? Could you add something clickable to the treeview item content to access the menu?